# Import csv file in hsqldb

Tags: database, csv, hsqldb

I tried to import a csv file into hsqldb by:

```
COPY TestDATA FROM 'C:/Users/Desktop/Data.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
```

However, I am only getting an error:

```
unexpected token: COPY / Error Code: -5581 / State: 42581
```

Is this possible in hsqldb? If not, whats another way to import a csv in hsqldb?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to import CSV files:

1. Use the SqlTool command line app to copy into a normal table
   http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_dsv-sect
2. Create a TEXT table with the CSV file as its data source
   http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html The contents of the TEXT table can then be copied into a normal table.